# aggregate date ranges with gaps in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, range, aggregate

I need to aggregate date ranges allowing for max 2 days gaps in between for each id. Any help would be much appreciated

```
create table tt ( id int, startdate date, stopdate date);  
Insert into TT values (1,'24/05/2010', '29/05/2010');
Insert into TT values (1,'30/05/2010', '22/06/2010');
Insert into TT values (10,'26/06/2012', '28/06/2012');
Insert into TT values (10,'29/06/2012', '30/06/2012');
Insert into TT values (10,'01/07/2012', '30/07/2012');
Insert into TT values (10,'03/08/2012', '30/12/2012');
insert into TT values (90,'08/03/2002', '16/03/2002');
insert into TT values (90,'31/01/2002', '15/02/2002');
insert into TT values (90,'15/02/2002', '28/02/2002');
insert into TT values (90,'31/01/2002', '15/02/2004');
insert into TT values (90,'15/02/2004', '15/04/2004');
insert into TT values (90,'01/03/2002', '07/03/2002');
```

expected output would be:

```
1     24/05/2010    22/06/2010
10    26/06/2012    30/07/2012
10    03/08/2012    30/12/2012 
90    31/01/2002    15/04/2004
```

Comment: can you please add expected result also to the question. ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're on 12c, you can use one of my favourite SQL features: pattern matching (match_recognize).

With this you need to define a pattern variable. This is where you'll check that the start date of the current row is within two days of the stop date for the previous row. Which is:

```
startdate <= prev ( stopdate ) + 2
```

The pattern you're searching for is any row, followed by zero or more rows that meet this criterium.

So you have an "always true" `strt` variable, followed by * (regular expression zero-or-more quantifier) occurrences of the within2 variable:

```
( strt within2* )
```

I'm guessing you also need to split the ranges up by ID. So I've added a partition by for this.

Put it all together and you get:

```
select * 
from   tt match_recognize (
  partition by id
  order by startdate, stopdate
  measures
    first ( startdate ) startdate, 
    last ( stopdate ) stopdate
  pattern ( strt within2* ) 
  define 
    within2 as startdate <= prev ( stopdate ) + 2
);

ID   STARTDATE    STOPDATE     
   1 24/05/2010   22/06/2010   
  10 26/06/2012   30/07/2012   
  10 03/08/2012   30/12/2012
```

If you want to know more about this, you can find [several match_recognize examples here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533477800346658909).

Comment: However, this will not work for the following subset, where stopdate = startdate = null, see example: 
`create table tt (id VARCHAR(8), startdate date, stopdate date);`  
`insert into TT values ('ALH002','01/09/2010 00:00', '21/02/2011 00:00');` 
`insert into TT values ('ALH002','21/02/2011 00:00', '06/06/2011 00:00');`
`insert into TT values ('ALH002','06/06/2011 00:00', '');`

it should result in the following row:
`ALH002 01/09/2010 00:00:00 06/06/2011  00:00:00`

Comment: That's just a matter of updating the stopdate in the measures clause to return the value you want; either the `max ( stopdate )` or the `last (nvl ( stop, start ))`

Comment: thanks! this will solve this particular problem. However, for ranges contained in another row, the script will produce incorrect output. I have updated the query above

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is here. Running the answer with the values you added to the question gives the output you've requested.

Comment: my mistake there, I corrected the input data to reflect the issue described earlier